# Angularjs unknown provider nvd3

Tags: javascript, angularjs, d3.js, frontend, nvd3.js

I am trying to use nvd3 to generate and update charts, as data changes dynamically. I felt I have indeed given the provider to my code, however I am running into this error and am unsure what I am doing wrong:

```
   Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: nvd3Provider <- nvd3
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.18/$injector/unpr?p0=nvd3Provider%20%3C-%20nvd3
    at https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.18/angular.js:78:12
    at https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.18/angular.js:3741:19
    at Object.getService [as get] (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.18/angular.js:3869:39)
    at https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.18/angular.js:3746:45
    at getService (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.18/angular.js:3869:39)
    at invoke (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.18/angular.js:3896:13)
    at Object.instantiate (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.18/angular.js:3917:23)
    at https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.18/angular.js:7201:28
    at link (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.18/angular-route.js:913:26)
    at nodeLinkFn (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.18/angular.js:6633:13) <div ng-view="" class="ng-scope">
```

This is my app:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['nvd3']);
```

This is my controller:

```
myApp.controller('myCtrl',['$scope','nvd3',
    function($scope){ 
               $scope.options =  { /*my json chart options */  };
               $scope.data = { /* my json data */ }
            }]);
```

I use this snippet in my index.html for the libraries:

```
<meta charset="utf-8">  <!-- it's important for d3.js -->
    <script src="js/bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bower_components/d3/d3.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bower_components/nvd3/nv.d3.js"></script> 
    <script src="js/bower_components/angular-nvd3/dist/angular-nvd3.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="js/bower_components/nvd3/nv.d3.css">
```

and try to generate the chart using:

```
<div ng-controller="myCtrl">
     <nvd3 options="options" data="data"></nvd3>
 </div>
```

Other (possibly irrelevant) information, is that I am using ngRoutes and firebase APIs.
Any advice or suggestions for further reading are appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need to inject `nvd3` in your controller:

Change:

```
myApp.controller('myCtrl',['$scope','nvd3',
    function($scope){ 
               $scope.options =  { /*my json chart options */  };
               $scope.data = { /* my json data */ }
            }]);
```

To:

```
myApp.controller('myCtrl',['$scope',
    function($scope){ 
               $scope.options =  { /*my json chart options */  };
               $scope.data = { /* my json data */ }
            }]);
```